# How should I configure dockercloud/haproxy to proxy https?

Tags: ssl, proxy, haproxy, docker, docker-compose

I am using the [dockercloud/haproxy](https://github.com/docker/dockercloud-haproxy#ssl-termination) image to proxy and balance incoming http requests.
The docker container should listen to port 443 and 80 (-> 443).

I am using Stackfiles and I've been redirecting the path `/api` with `VIRTUAL_HOST=*/api/*`.

Adding SSL support, I am not sure if I have to replace line breaks on the `DEFAULT_SSL_CERT` param.
For the http -> https redirect I am using the `FORCE_SSL` param.

What config should I use for the forward? I am on the right way with this config?

This is my current stackfile:

```
api:
  autoredeploy: true
  environment:
    - "VIRTUAL_HOST=*/api/*"
    - "VIRTUAL_HOST_WEIGHT=1"
    - "FORCE_SSL=yes"
  image: "anaibol/webapp-api:latest"
web:
  autoredeploy: true
  environment:
    - "VIRTUAL_HOST=*"
    - "VIRTUAL_HOST_WEIGHT=0"
    - "FORCE_SSL=yes"
  image: "anaibol/webapp:latest"
  links:
    - api
lb:
  image: "dockercloud/haproxy:latest"
  links:
    - api
    - web
  ports:
    - "443:443"
    - "80:80"
  roles:
    - global
  environment:
    - "DEFAULT_SSL_CERT=-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n...\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was setting `VIRTUAL_HOST` like so:

`VIRTUAL_HOST=*/api*, https://*/api*`

Also `DEFAULT_SSL_CERT` line breaks are fine.